# Changing timer interval after first iteration has completed

Tags: javascript

In pure javascript, I am presently using a timer to change six background images. I have set the script to infinitely repeat the looping as long as the window is open. However, after the first loop, I would like to reset the timer increment value from 3250 milliseconds to say 7000 milliseconds for all loops after the first one has completed at the faster rate.

```
<script>
  function shiftbackgrd(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;

    function IncrementAnswersBkgrnds() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }

    var swap = window.setInterval(IncrementAnswersBkgrnds, interval);
  }
  shiftbackgrd(3250, 7); //milliseconds, frames
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to know when to switch and then use `clearInterval` to clear the old and set a new interval. You can use a flag that gets set the first time your counter hits the value.

```js
function shiftbackgrd(interval, interval2, frames) {
  var int = 1;
  var allSeen = false

  function IncrementAnswersBkgrnds() {
    // do something
    console.log("call:", int);

    int++;
    if (int === frames) {
      int = 1;
      if (!allSeen) {
        console.log("All seen, changing to new interval")
        allSeen = true
        window.clearInterval(swap)
        swap = window.setInterval(IncrementAnswersBkgrnds, interval2)
      }
    }
  }

  var swap = window.setInterval(IncrementAnswersBkgrnds, interval);
}
shiftbackgrd(500, 1500, 7); //milliseconds, frames
```

Comment: PERFECT Answer Mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change it on the first call you can simply use setTimeout for the first call, and then have the function recurse on its own after that.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  shiftbackgrd(7000, 7); //milliseconds, frames
}, 3250)
```

With your original code you will still need to have your `shiftbackgrd` function instantly call `IncrementAnswersBkgrnds` right before starting the setInterval for this to fully work.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I substituted your setTimeout(function () { ... code in place of my single line (and even moved it to various positions. I am not able to get it to work. If it is possible to work, it seems likely in my lack of imbibing your last instruction dealing with getting, "have your shiftbackgrd function instantly call". I am at a loss here.

Comment: @GladHeart - don't fret :) I also believe I may have misunderstood your question. Perhaps Mark Meyer's answer is more suitable.

Comment: Refer to @MarkMeyer 's perfect and excellent answer as it relates to the question. I am adding information I have discovered and am using regarding changing the timing of background changes on a one off basis without using the window.clearInterval(swap). By just specifying a given frame and using the shiftbackgrd milliseconds, one can set the specified frame(s) to however many multiples of the millisecond cycle they wish without disturbing the frame count. I am not trying to answer my own question but need to use the answer space to demonstrate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to @MarkMeyer 's perfect and excellent answer as it relates to the question. I am adding information I have discovered and am using regarding changing the timing of background changes on a one off basis without using the window.clearInterval(swap). By just specifying a given frame and using the shiftbackgrd milliseconds, one can set the specified frame(s) to however many multiples of the millisecond cycle they wish without disturbing the frame count. I am not trying to answer my own question but need to use the answer space to demonstrate the code.

```
<script>

var int = 0;
var intRepeat = 0; //incrimented to loop background by multiples of shiftbackgrd milliseconds

function shiftbackgrd(interval, frames)
{"use strict";
var swap = window.setInterval(IncrementHubrisBkgrnds, interval);

    function IncrementHubrisBkgrnds()
    {
    if(int === 15 ) {clearInterval(swap);}

        while (int !== 15 )
        {
        // allows all 16 frames to be set [frames b0, through b15] via int++

            int++;
            document.body.id = "b"+int;

            if(int !== 15 ) {break;}
            // kicks out of while loop on each incriment so it doesn't increment from b0 to b15 without a transitioning of backgrounds for frames preceeding b15
        }


        //Below two ifs create loops of specified background frames increasing their display time
        if(int == 1 && intRepeat <= (0 + 0) ) {
        // first number of intRepeat is starting off as it was set as a var = 0
        // second number of intRepeat chosen will reload chosen window x times more [0 + '0' = 1 when intRepeat++ times more making two times when including the initial background load]

            intRepeat++;
            int = 0;
            // 0 here with the int++ becomes document.body.id = "b"+int; of b1 repeating
        }
        if(int == 14 && intRepeat <= (1 + 1) ) {
        // first number of intRepeat is where it left off its count in last loop at intRepeat 1
        // second number of intRepeat chosen will reload frame b14 that many times more [using just '0' would be once; using '1' makes two times more in addition to the initial load]

            intRepeat++;
            int = 13;
            // 13 here with the int++ becomes document.body.id = "b"+int; of b14 repeating
        }


    }
}

shiftbackgrd(2500, 15); //milliseconds, frames
// Only needs fifteen background changes beyound the intial auto load of background 'b0'.

</script>
```